Most energy efficient way to decrease pressure
I'm currently working on a solar still design to enhance solar desalination productivity. One of the ways to increase productivity was to decrease humidity and pressure. I simply want to know the best approach to achieving this while using as little energy as possible.

decrease humidity and pressure where?

productivity is a measure of human output.  Tell us again what you are trying to do.  Also what type of humidity you are referencing.

A solar driven pump.

Productivity is how much water is condensed and collected from the solar still. What I mean by "decrease humidity and pressure" is to decrease them inside the solar still so that water evaporates faster. The humidity is produced by the water evaporating

I know a solar-driven pump can be used but I've seen research papers use fans to speed up air molecules which decreases pressure. Furthermore, a solar-driven pump needs a large solar panel because of its high electricity consumption.

You could decrease the temperature of your collector, for example, use evaporative cooling. This will decrease the vapor pressure of the water in the air and enhance evaporation.

Doing this at scale, you have a closed-loop liquid solar heat concentrator loop. This transfers heat in sequence to several brine containers at different pressures - lower pressure in each one as the temp of the loop drops. Each one has a vapor extraction pump to send the vapor over to the condenser. You usually spray the brine onto the heat exchanger to get it to flash into vapor. For a well-designed multi-element desalination system designed entirely for solar, the ratio of electrical power to captured thermal power is about 1:3.
see my answer here for a good reference - Is distillation inferior to reverse osmosis in desalination?

I'm doing what's called a solar-driven interfacial desalination. A hydrogel is used to float a top of the water and concentrate heat on the surface. A 3d cylinder design can be used to further enhance the evaporation rate. This system can't be implemented in a multi-element desalination system. So I do want to know what you think of the design and how to implement a pump to for this specific design
